# How to allow multiple different IList to be called through a method

Tags: c#, list

I have a method which requires an IList to be defined when calling. It works great, however, as the project has expanded, we have continuously copy/pasted the code, and changed the type of the list, as these are coming from Models. Is there a simple way without defining it as dynamic to streamline the process so we can just re-use this method?

We tried dynamic but the tech lead is against using dynamic.

```
private int ReportDataWriter(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, IList<ReportGridColumnModel> headerColumns, IList<CoolModel> modelData, int rowIndex) 
{
    var dataHeaderCount = headerColumns.Count();
    var totalItems = modelData.Count;
    var lineIndex = rowIndex;

    for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) 
    {
        var colIndex = 1;
        foreach (var dataHeader in headerColumns) 
        {
            worksheet.DataWriter(dataHeader, rowIndex, colIndex, colIndex);
            using (var cell = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++]) 
            {
                var valueToWrite = GetColumnValue(dataHeader.Field, modelData[i]);
                cell.Value = valueToWrite;

                worksheet.Column(colIndex - 1).AutoFit();

                if (modelData[i].IsCatRow) 
                {
                    worksheet.SetBackGroundColor(ExcelFillStyle.Solid, Color.LightGray, rowIndex,
                        dataHeaderCount, 1);
                }
            }
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }

    if (modelData[0].CategoryTitle == ReportConstants.Total) 
    {
        worksheet.SetBottomBorder(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin, Color.Black, lineIndex, dataHeaderCount, 1);
    }

    return rowIndex;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "_changed the name of the list_"? Lists don't have names...

Comment: Do you mean the list type changes?

Comment: If you are only changing the `Type` that the `IList` objects contain, then this could easily be made generic as long as you can constrain `T1` to types that have a `Field` property, and are acceptable as the first parameter to the `DataWriter` method, and that you can constrain `T2` to types that have `IsCatRow` and `CategoryTitle` properties, and are acceptable as a second parameter to the `GetColumnValue` method.

Comment: Yes, I meant type, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it generic with constraints on the generic types.

```
public int DataWriter<THeader, TModel>(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, IList<THeader> headerColumns, IList<TModel> modelData, int rowIndex) 
    where THeader: IHeader 
    where TModel: IModel 
{
    var dataHeaderCount = headerColumns.Count();
    var totalItems = modelData.Count;
    var lineIndex = rowIndex;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) 
    {
        var colIndex = 1;
        foreach (var dataHeader in headerColumns) {
            worksheet.DataWriter(dataHeader, rowIndex, colIndex, colIndex);
            using (var cell = worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex++]) {
                var valueToWrite = GetColumnValue(dataHeader.Field, modelData[i]);
                cell.Value = valueToWrite;

                worksheet.Column(colIndex - 1).AutoFit();

                if (modelData[i].IsCatRow) {
                    worksheet.SetBackGroundColor(ExcelFillStyle.Solid, Color.LightGray, rowIndex,
                        dataHeaderCount, 1);
                }

            }
        }
        rowIndex++;
    }
    if (modelData[0].CategoryTitle == ReportConstants.Total) {
        worksheet.SetBottomBorder(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin, Color.Black, lineIndex, dataHeaderCount, 1);
    }
    return rowIndex;
}
```

The interfaces

```
public interface IHeader
{
    string Field { get; }
}
public interface IModel
{
    string CategoryTitle { get; }
    bool IsCatRow { get; }
}
```

To use it, make sure all header column classes implements the `IHeader` interface and each model implements `IModel`.

Usage example:

```
var headers = new List<ReportGridColumnModel>();
var models = new List<CoolModel>();
var worksheet = new ExcelWorksheet();

var r = DataWriter(worksheet, headers, models);
```

Another option is, instead of using interfaces, use abstract classes which implements the properties and all derived classes could then use the method the same way.

Comment: Oops, i made rather quite the blunder. It just did take some time to sink into my brain. `IList<T>` is of course NOT covariant, `IEnumerable<T>` is. So, my first comment (deleted now) is actually not true. At all. I am terribly sorry for my brain fart... :-( (That means, the original form of your answer with the generic method should actually be the working one. Or, the current method could be altered to support IEnumerable's by changing the for-loop into a foreach-loop; but this would admittedly be the somewhat bigger code change compared to making the method generic...)

Comment: @elgonzo If you made the blunder then so did I :) reverted the edit. Don't want to change the the implementation to much but you are absolutly correct about the IEnumerable. Thanks for the feedback